# C# ,How to I make bindable string picker?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin

I'm pretty new to C#, I'm trying to make an app with Xamarin forms. I want a picker, what can choose from ($,£,etc) values. Keep in mind that I'm using SQLite.net. Soo, for learning how to make an app I'm using an example from github. There is a long code for bindablepicker:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TodoScheduler.Controls
{
    public class BindablePicker : Picker
    {
        bool _disableNestedCalls;

        public static readonly BindableProperty PickerTitleProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("PickerTitle", typeof(string), typeof(BindablePicker),
                null);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(BindablePicker),
                null, propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);

        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("SelectedItem", typeof(Object), typeof(BindablePicker),
                null, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnSelectedItemChanged);

        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedValueProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("SelectedValue", typeof(Object), typeof(BindablePicker),
                null, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnSelectedValueChanged);

        public String DisplayMemberPath { get; set; }

        public string PickerTitle
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PickerTitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PickerTitleProperty, value); }
        }

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set
            {
                if (this.SelectedItem != value)
                {
                    SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
                    InternalSelectedItemChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public object SelectedValue
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value);
                InternalSelectedValueChanged();
            }
        }

        public string SelectedValuePath { get; set; }

        public BindablePicker()
        {
            this.SelectedIndexChanged += OnSelectedIndexChanged;
        }

        public event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> ItemSelected;

        void InstanceOnItemsSourceChanged(Object oldValue, Object newValue)
        {
            _disableNestedCalls = true;

            this.Items.Clear();
            var oldCollectionINotifyCollectionChanged = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (oldCollectionINotifyCollectionChanged != null)
            {
                oldCollectionINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
            }
            var newCollectionINotifyCollectionChanged = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (newCollectionINotifyCollectionChanged != null)
            {
                newCollectionINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
            }
            if (!Equals(newValue, null))
            {
                var hasDisplayMemberPath = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.DisplayMemberPath);
                foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)newValue)
                {
                    if (hasDisplayMemberPath)
                    {
                        var type = item.GetType();
                        var prop = type.GetRuntimeProperty(this.DisplayMemberPath);
                        this.Items.Add(prop.GetValue(item).ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Items.Add(item.ToString());
                    }
                }

                this.SelectedIndex = -1;  // select first item by default
                this._disableNestedCalls = false;

                if (this.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    this.InternalSelectedItemChanged();
                }
                else if (hasDisplayMemberPath && this.SelectedValue != null)
                {
                    this.InternalSelectedValueChanged();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _disableNestedCalls = true;
                this.SelectedIndex = -1;
                this.SelectedItem = null;
                this.SelectedValue = null;
                _disableNestedCalls = false;
            }
        }

        void InternalSelectedItemChanged()
        {
            if (_disableNestedCalls)
            {
                return;
            }

            var selectedIndex = -1;
            Object selectedValue = null;

            if (this.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                var index = 0;

                var hasSelectedValuePath = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SelectedValuePath);

                foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
                {
                    if (item != null && item.Equals(this.SelectedItem))
                    {
                        selectedIndex = index;
                        if (hasSelectedValuePath)
                        {
                            var type = item.GetType();
                            var prop = type.GetRuntimeProperty(this.SelectedValuePath);
                            selectedValue = prop.GetValue(item);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }
            _disableNestedCalls = true;
            this.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
            this.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;        
            _disableNestedCalls = false;
        }

        void InternalSelectedValueChanged()
        {
            if (_disableNestedCalls)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SelectedValuePath))
            {
                return;
            }

            var selectedIndex = -1;

            Object selectedItem = null;

            var hasSelectedValuePath = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SelectedValuePath);

            if (this.ItemsSource != null && hasSelectedValuePath)
            {
                var index = 0;

                foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        var type = item.GetType();
                        var prop = type.GetRuntimeProperty(this.SelectedValuePath);
                        if (Object.Equals(prop.GetValue(item), this.SelectedValue))
                        {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                            selectedItem = item;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }
            _disableNestedCalls = true;
            this.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
            this.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
            _disableNestedCalls = false;
        }

        void ItemsSource_CollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var hasDisplayMemberPath = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.DisplayMemberPath);
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    if (hasDisplayMemberPath)
                    {
                        var type = item.GetType();
                        var prop = type.GetRuntimeProperty(this.DisplayMemberPath);
                        this.Items.Add(prop.GetValue(item).ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Items.Add(item.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    if (hasDisplayMemberPath)
                    {
                        var type = item.GetType();
                        var prop = type.GetRuntimeProperty(this.DisplayMemberPath);
                        this.Items.Remove(prop.GetValue(item).ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Items.Remove(item.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    if (hasDisplayMemberPath)
                    {
                        var type = item.GetType();
                        var prop = type.GetRuntimeProperty(this.DisplayMemberPath);
                        this.Items.Remove(prop.GetValue(item).ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var index = this.Items.IndexOf(item.ToString());
                        if (index > -1)
                        {
                            this.Items[index] = item.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                this.Items.Clear();

                if (e.NewItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        if (hasDisplayMemberPath)
                        {
                            var type = item.GetType();
                            var prop = type.GetRuntimeProperty(this.DisplayMemberPath);
                            this.Items.Remove(prop.GetValue(item).ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var index = this.Items.IndexOf(item.ToString());
                            if (index > -1)
                            {
                                this.Items[index] = item.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _disableNestedCalls = true;
                    this.SelectedItem = null;
                    this.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    this.SelectedValue = null;
                    _disableNestedCalls = false;

                }
            }
        }

        static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
        {
            if (Equals(newValue, null) && Equals(oldValue, null))
            {
                return;
            }

            var picker = (BindablePicker)bindable;
            picker.InstanceOnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        }

        void OnSelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_disableNestedCalls)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.SelectedIndex < 0 || this.ItemsSource == null || !this.ItemsSource.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
            {
                _disableNestedCalls = true;

                if (this.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    //this.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    this.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }

                this.SelectedItem = null;
                this.SelectedValue = null;
                _disableNestedCalls = false;
                return;
            }

            _disableNestedCalls = true;

            var index = 0;
            var hasSelectedValuePath = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SelectedValuePath);

            foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
            {
                if (index == this.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    this.SelectedItem = item;

                    if (hasSelectedValuePath)
                    {
                        var type = item.GetType();
                        var prop = type.GetRuntimeProperty(this.SelectedValuePath);
                        this.SelectedValue = prop.GetValue(item);
                    }

                    break;
                }
                index++;
            }

            _disableNestedCalls = false;
        }

        static void OnSelectedItemChanged(BindableObject bindable, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
        {
            var boundPicker = (BindablePicker)bindable;
            boundPicker.ItemSelected?.Invoke(boundPicker, new SelectedItemChangedEventArgs(newValue));
            boundPicker.InternalSelectedItemChanged();
        }

        static void OnSelectedValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
        {
            var boundPicker = (BindablePicker)bindable;
            boundPicker.InternalSelectedValueChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The form code:

```
            <controls:BindablePicker Margin="20,5"
                                                                      ItemsSource="{Binding PriorityList}"
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding Priority, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                                 Title="Choose"
                                 VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
```

Model:

```
TodoPriority _priority = TodoPriority.Low;
    [NotNull] public TodoPriority Priority {
        get { return _priority; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _priority, value); }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
   TodoPriority _priority = TodoPriority.Low;
    public TodoPriority Priority
    {
        get { return _priority; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _priority, value); }
    }

    IEnumerable<TodoPriority> _priorityList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TodoPriority)).Cast<TodoPriority>();
    public IEnumerable<TodoPriority> PriorityList
    {
        get { return _priorityList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _priorityList, value); }
    }
```

TodoPriority:

```
    namespace TodoScheduler.Enums
{
    public enum TodoPriority
    {
        Low = 0,
        Normal,
        High
    }
}
```

At the moment I can choose from picker (low,normal,high), but how can I change this? I know I cant change those values from Todopriority to currency token, because its enum. I tried to make them all strings, but then I caught on a problem that how I can make these values. I know its a bit dumb question, but I've search alot and cant figute it out.

Comment: XF now has a built in bindable Picker: https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-for-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a class to represent each picker item

```
class PriorityPickerValue {

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public TodoPriority Priority { get; set; }

}
```

That way you can specify how your values look in the picker and still have access to the TodoPriority property